# numpy requires System Python 2.7 to install

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I'm trying to learn python (in the process of installing numpy 1.8.0 in order to install BioPython), and am receiving the error "numpy requires System Python 2.7 to install" when I try to put numpy on my HD. I have recently updated my operating system from Mac OS X 10.6 to Mavericks, and am using python 2.7 (although other versions are installed on my computer). I am not an expert in terms of manually installing programs on mac, so there may be a simple solution to this, but I cannot understand why the OS is telling me that the version of python I'm using (for instance, if I type "python -V", the response is "Python 2.7.5") is not there.

Any insights are appreciated!
Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 5):

Odds are, you're trying to use a 32-bit NumPy from a 64 bit Python.

[In order to check your Python architecture](http://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#cross-platform), you can open up your interactive session and type

```
>>> import sys
>>> is_64bits = sys.maxsize > 2**32
>>> is_64bits
# output will be True or False
```

Rather than offering anything new, I'll distill and link to a few other SO answers:

1) To fix this, you can [install a 32-bit Python](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.6/) rather than using OSX's preinstalled Python, then set it as your default `python` in your `PATH` (this is a route recommended by the Python website anyway).

[Reference to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684254/i-cannot-install-numpy-because-it-cant-find-python-2-7-althought-i-have-instal)

2) You can install Python through the [Enthought distribution](https://www.enthought.com/)

[Reference to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566554/osx-numpy-scipy-requires-python-2-6-to-install)